# CKWebSpeech in Primefaces

Tags: primefaces, ckeditor

I am trying to implement CKWebSpeech in primefaces. I already have a CKEditor in my page. I have followed the below steps:
1. copied the CKWebSpeech folder under ckeditor/plugins folder.
2. Modified the config.js as mentioned in https://tech.ultranaco.com/webspeech/ckwebspeech

When I invoke the page, the editor is not displayed & I get the below error in my WildFly server console

[javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-9) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, ckeditor/plugins/ckwebspeech/plugin.js, from library, primefaces

Can someone help me resolve this problem?

Comment: Are you using raw CKEditor JS code or are you using Primefaces Extensions CKEditor?  If you are using Raw CKEditor JS code you generated yourself from the CKEditor site I can't see why that would not just work.

Comment: I am using the raw  CKEditor JS code generated from the site. Now I am not getting any exception. Would like to know how to specify the microphone option in the xhtml file currently I have below options only.                                                            
 CKEDITOR.replace('editor', { height : '130px',toolbar: [[ 'Bold','-','Italic','-','Underline','-','Strike' ], [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList' ], [ 'Outdent','-','Indent' ],
['SpellChecker'],[ 'Subscript','-','Superscript' ], [ 'Maximize' ]]});

Comment: It looks like the microphone speech to text options may be a little tricky:  https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10695

Comment: The problem i currently have is the microphone icon is not displaying in the CKEditor though I have added [ 'Maximize', 'ckwebspeech' ], Maximize icon is displaying, but not microphone. How do i get it displayed?

Comment: Any help on the above is appreciated. I am still not able to get the microphone to be displayed on the page.